# Writing String to File in C

Tags: html, c, file, creation

I am in the process of writing an HTTP client that basically goes to a webpage and downloads the content to a separate file, which the user defines. I am having trouble not with the act of writing to a file itself, but I'm getting a strange problem.  I'll show a couple of the code snippets below, but basically when there is a

```
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", htmlcontent);
```

where htmlcontent is defined as

```
    char *htmlcontent;
```

it prints out the entire HTML page information to the standard output.  I can also redirect this output to a file in the command line by saying >myfile.txt (Yes, I want to compare the text files instead of html files).

But when I do something like this:

```
    fprintf(savedfile, "%s", htmlcontent);
```

where savedfile is defined as

```
    FILE *savedfile;
```

and it is opened like this:

```
    savedfile = fopen(filename, "w");
```

where filename is defined as

```
    char *filename;
```

and is set equal to the command line argument that corresponds to it.  When I do the second type of fprintf to print it out to my file instead of the standard output, I do not get the same thing and i can't figure out why.  Can anybody help me understand why there would be any difference?  If you want me to post the two different programs so you can see them in their entirety just let me know and I'll do that.

Comment: What difference do you see?

Comment: @Thomas, The difference is the entirety of the HTML code vs. a small segment of it.  Before I tried writing the string to the file, I put in a print statement that printed what the string should contain, and this went to stdout. Directly after that line in the code, I wrote the print statement that wrote the same string to the file. However, what I got in stdout and what was actually in the file were two different things. The stdout version contained all the HTML code for the page I was trying to download while the file only contained a small part of it.

Comment: How large is the HTML code?

Comment: For the page that I've been testing it with, the code is between 800 and 900 lines in a text editor.  The problematic portions I'm getting range between 50 and 150 lines roughly, and those numbers varied because I've tried different methods and function calls for writing to the file.

Comment: Also, the segments don't always necessarily start in the same place.  It could start in the beginning, it could start somewhere in the middle, it varies.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really told us *what* the difference is between the two output methods but, based on the information given, there should be none.

Functionally, there's no difference between writing to `stdout` and any other properly opened output stream (there are some *behavioural* differences like buffering but they shouldn't affect the output).

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> cat xyzzy.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char *filename = "xyzzy.txt";
    char *html = "<tag>some markup</tag>\n";

    FILE *xyzzy = fopen (filename, "w"); // should error check

    fprintf (stdout, "%s", html);
    fprintf (xyzzy, "%s", html);

    fclose (xyzzy);

    return 0;
}

pax> ./xyzzy
<tag>some markup</tag>

pax> cat xyzzy.txt
<tag>some markup</tag>
```

As you can see, both the `xyzzy.txt` file and the standard output of the program contain the same information.

Comment: Exactly, I understand that there should be no difference at all in what the output is.  That is why I am so dumbfounded.  Before I tried writing the string to the file, I put in a print statement that printed what the string should contain, and this went to stdout.  Directly after that line in the code, I wrote the print statement that wrote the same string to the file.  However, what I got in stdout and what was actually in the file were two different things.  The stdout version contained all the HTML code for the page I was trying to download while the file only contained a small part of it.